# correct PHP headers for pdf file download

Tags: php, pdf, header

I'm really struggling to get my application to open a pdf when the user clicks on a link.

So far the anchor tag redirects to a page which sends headers that are:

```
$filename='./pdf/jobs/pdffile.pdf;

$url_download = BASE_URL . RELATIVE_PATH . $filename;

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='$filename");
readfile("downloaded.pdf");
```

this doesn't seem to work, has anybody successfully sorted this problem in the past?

Comment: Typo? Try adding a `'` `$filename='./pdf/jobs/pdffile.pdf';` and in this line `header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='$filename");` missing quotation mark.

Comment: How/why are you using `$url_download` ?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Example 2 on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp) shows what you are trying to achieve.

> ```
> <?php
> header("Content-type:application/pdf");
>
> // It will be called downloaded.pdf
> header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=\"downloaded.pdf\"");
>
> // The PDF source is in original.pdf
> readfile("original.pdf");
> ?>
> ```

Also remember that,

> It is important to notice that header() must be called before any
> actual output is sent (In PHP 4 and later, you can use output
> buffering to solve this problem)

Comment: Remember to remove the single quotes around the file name. If you use filename='downloaded.pdf', some browsers will try to save the file with the quotes in the filename. I recently experienced this on OSX.

Comment: `readfile()` very bad for large files size, because when some users want to download, each downloading files buffer on server ram!!!

Comment: Why on earth would a PDF have HTML tags?

Comment: It results with a damaged file

Comment: OSX can handle double quote better `;filename=\"downloaded.pdf\"`

Answer (score 34):

```
$name = 'file.pdf';
//file_get_contents is standard function
$content = file_get_contents($name);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen( $content ));
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="' . $name . '"');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
echo $content;
```

Comment: Note that loading the entire file content into a variable may collide with the memory limit. That's why `readfile()` is the preferred solution.

Comment: I was having problem in Edge browser not able to detect PDF , this code fix it.
Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 14):

There are some things to be considered in your code.

First, write those headers correctly. You will never see any server sending `Content-type:application/pdf`, the header is `Content-Type: application/pdf`, spaced, with capitalized first letters etc.

The file name in `Content-Disposition` is the file name only, not the full path to it, and altrough I don't know if its mandatory or not, this name comes wrapped in `"`  not `'`. Also, your last `'` is missing.

`Content-Disposition: inline` implies the file should be displayed, not downloaded. Use `attachment` instead.

In addition, make the file extension in upper case to make it compatible with some mobile devices. (**Update**: Pretty sure only Blackberries had this problem, but the world moved on from those so this may be no longer a concern)

All that being said, your code should look more like this:

```
<?php

    $filename = './pdf/jobs/pdffile.pdf';

    $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
    $sendname = $fileinfo['filename'] . '.' . strtoupper($fileinfo['extension']);

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$sendname\"");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
```

Technically `Content-Length` is optional but it is important if you want the user to be able to keep track of the download progress, and detect if the download was interrupted before the end. When using it you have to make sure you won't be send anything along with the file data. Make sure there is absolutely nothing before `<?php` or after `?>`, not even an empty line.

Comment: You don't need the closing tag `?>`. In this case, it's better to remove it.

Comment: Fairly sure that enclosing a header-supplied filename in single quotes comprehensively breaks the downloading, so as you suggest, that makes a big difference.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem recently and this helped me:

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILENAME"'); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 
    header('Pragma: public'); 
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("PATH/TO/FILE")); 
    ob_clean(); 
    flush(); 
    readfile(PATH/TO/FILE);      
    exit();
```

I found this answer [here](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10372951-RESOLVED-Can-t-open-pdf-file-downloaded-via-php-header)

Comment: ob_start( ); at the top ensures data corruption

Comment: `ob_start()` did not helped me but when i added `ob_clean()` and `flush()` it worked!

Comment: this one works. Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this, `readfile` need the full file path.

```
        $filename='/pdf/jobs/pdffile.pdf';            
        $url_download = BASE_URL . RELATIVE_PATH . $filename;            

        //header("Content-type:application/pdf");   
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");                       
        header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='".basename($filename)."'");            
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
        header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly                     
        readfile($filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the size of file...

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

And this line is wrong:

> header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='$filename");

You messed up quotas.

Comment: No, you don't need to give the size of the file. That's also a possible source for bugs.

Comment: Depends of PDF plugin version. It is safe to give it.

Comment: cannot get this to work.  What is the $file variable i am testing the size of?  Is it the file URL ./pdf/jobs/pdftitle.pdf ?

Comment: yes, its is the file location... maybe you are messing up paths? try giving absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");

// It will be called downloaded.pdf thats mean define file name would be show

header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=  $fileName  ");

// The PDF source is in original.pdf

readfile($file_url);
```