# Download a pdf only if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf, checkbox

i created a php page Download a PDF file only if a checkbox is checked. i open the pdf file when checkbox is click by the user but i need give direct download the PDF file when user click. 
pls help it

```js
 <script>
 function toggleCheckbox(element)
 {

   window.open('pdf/Code_of_Med_Ethics-a.pdf') ;
 }
 </script>
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this.id)" name="click" value="agree" id="click"} ?> >
```

Comment: Have You searched for this first?

Comment: Why is this question tagged in php

Comment: i tag coz i need results either in php or javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#click").is(':checked')){
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'pdf/Code_of_Med_Ethics-a.pdf';
}
```

Comment: i want download the fileon checked not open the pdf. this open the file.

Comment: @AmitKumar - that's because you're sending the wrong headers, and that can't be fixed with javascript, you have to send the right headers to start a download in PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleCheckbox(this.id)" name="click" value="agree" id="click" > 
<script>
 function toggleCheckbox(element)
 {
    if(document.getElementById(element).checked) {
       window.open('pdf/Code_of_Med_Ethics-a.pdf') ;
    }   
}
</script>
```