# how to pass number of hits count based on button action in php

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

We are developing web sit. We have button.In button action we placed PDF file downloading.Working fine.But We need How do I count download my PDF file  from my website.

We tried like this but We not get.

```
<?php
//$Down=$_GET['Down'];
$a="hello";
$i=0;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=0;
    function submitForm()
    {
        <?php
        $i = @file_get_contents('count.txt'); // read the hit count from file
        echo $i; //  display the hit count
        $i++; // increment the hit count by 1
        @file_put_contents('count.txt', $i); // store the new hit count
        ?>  
    }
</script>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="submitForm()" value="submit 1" />
</body>
</html>
```

We got nothing .We are new to `PHP` Please guide to us.

Comment: How are you downloading the PDF ?

Comment: @SpartakusMd most likely the form target, unsure though.

Comment: Save you $i variable with $_SESSION; Do something like $_SESSION['count'] = $i; Don't forget to enable sessions with "session_start()" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: @SpartakusMd downloading like this 
<a  href="http://192.168.3.134:8080/Helphands/forTest.txt" download  onclick="redirect();">

Comment: use a database for this or Ajax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- we don't have database we have .txt File in server we need count will be update in .txt  file

Comment: then Ajax would be a good candidate if you want to use JS ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can download you PDF and count at form submit:

```
<?php
$i=0;
$i = (int) @file_get_contents('count.txt'); // read the hit count from file
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $i++; // increment the hit count by 1
    @file_put_contents('count.txt', $i); // store the new hit count
    // Download
    $file = 'filename.pdf';
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
}
```

Now use `echo $i;` where you want to display the number of downloads.

In html the form should be:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download">
</form>
```

Comment: `$file = 'filename.pdf'` <= missing semi-colon - *parse error*

Comment: @SpartakusMd thanks so much we need exact this but we need Display count We tried like this echo $i but it's not displayed

Comment: @SpartakusMd thanks for update we tried like this 
 <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download" onclick="hitCount();">
 <label><?php $sss=@file_get_contents('count.txt');  echo $sss;?></label>
</form>

but it's not update button click Please guide to us .we are new to this

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing PHP with Javascript, that won't work out at all. The best solution would be to create a PHP Script which does the counting as shown above and after that delivers the PDF as attachment.

Some examples:

[How to make a PDF FIle Downloadble in HTML Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364946/how-to-make-pdf-file-downloadable-in-html-link)

[Correct PDF Headers for File Download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download)