# php script to download PDF files

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I am trying to create a download link for each users in the database to download a each of their PDF files. I have used the following code

```
$sqlh = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_health", $con) or die(mysql_error());
       $no = 1;
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sqlh)){
            $no++;
             $data['link'];
            echo "<a href='view.php?id=" .$data['health_id']. "'>Download</a>";

        }
```

my view.php is

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_health WHERE health_id='".$_GET['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());
echo $_GET['id'];
$data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$file = $data['link'];
$name = "health/".$file;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". urlencode($file));
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($name));
$fp = fopen($name, "r");
  //echo fread($fp, 65536);
readfile($fp);

  fclose($fp); }
```

the pdf can be downloaded but when open to view its empty.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correct PHP headers for pdf file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download)

Comment: no, its still the same

Comment: Use header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); instead, might work fine

Comment: It doesnt show the contents of the pdf, but the url shows file:///C:/Users/LIKI/AppData/Local/Temp/Quality_Plan_Template-4.pdf