# htaccess: disallow all pdf files but allow from php script (file download script)

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf, mod-rewrite, file-access

I wrote a small download script to hide the file path, the file "get_file.php" handles everything.
next step I would like to disallow with htaccess all pdf-files from direct access trough the browser (if anybody knows the exact url to the file), but still provide access to the file with my "get_file.php".

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ - [F]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.pdf[?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: beat me to it. I had perpared a similar answer, but cleared everything when I saw your answer

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

**get_file.php**

```
<?php
    // You can add extra codes to get your pdf file name here
    $file = 'file.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1st step - htaccess - there are different ways I usually use FilesMatch:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

2nd step is at your PHP file - you have just to use local path to load it and display it..
/path/to/file.pdf
Here are examples how to export it for the clients : [correct PHP headers for pdf file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download)