# mpdf renders wrong in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer, pdf, rendering, mpdf

I'm using MPDF (0.6) to render a PDF. This works fine in Chrome but Internet Explorer has to be a pain in the ass again. Due to limitations by the company I work for there is no reliable version of Chrome or FireFox available and I'm stuck to make it work in Internet Explorer.

The version available is 11.0.9600.17728. And the PDF renders like so (don't mind the TCPDF tab, I'm really using MPDF ;)):

[image]

Is there a setting I'm unaware of?

My implementation is quite simple (following the basic getting started example)

```
public function getPDF()
{
    require_once('../MPDF60/mpdf.php');

    $mpdf = new MPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('my pdf');
    $mpdf->Output();

    exit;
}
```

Below are the request headers and response headers:
[image]

[image]

Again, in Chrome it's working good (but I have that installed on the server, and is not available to the work stations). Suggestions?

Comment: I have not worked with mpdf but think it is possibly a header issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the Output method sets all headers.

Comment: What headers are you sending to the browser?

Comment: I don't think I'll ever get it to work. Tried to load some of the examples in IE but none of them render. Screen turns gray and it seems to silently crash. I'll head over to another PDF library.

Comment: And I'll have to revert that comment. I'm facing the same issues using TCPDF. It's something in IE, while the examples provided by TCPDF do work in IE.

Comment: then you should check the TCPDF headers and look for any differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior was caused by a `HTTP-500` error and then reload the page. Not really sure why, but when opening a new tab it works again. Somehow IE keeps some data in a tab's memory/state together with TCPDF.