# Cannot open PDF file downloaded using php

Tags: php

I am using the following php code to make pdf file download. I am able to download the pdf file but cannot open it. What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me?
download.php

```
<?php
$file = 'Rev.pdf';
$filepath = "doc/" . $file;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filepath));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filepath);
exit;
?>
```

Updated:
When I try to open it after download on browser, I get following error.
[image]

Update2:
Following is my HTML

```
<a href="download.php">download</a>
```

Update3: SOLVED
First of all I want to say sorry to make you all trouble. I have solved the  issue. Actually my PDF file itself was corrupted. So I created new pdf file and it's working well. Once again thank you all for hearing my problem and giving suggestions.

Comment: what happen when you open it?

Comment: I have updated my question adding error message. I can either open it from browser nor from downloaded folder.

Comment: save the file, then open it locally with a text editor, check the top and bottom for php errors

Comment: Tried to open it on text editor but file is empty. I tried with .docx file instead of PDF and it is working well. What's wrong with with my PDF file.

Comment: what does your [PHP error log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
```

Try this

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Also review this:

- [How to make PDF file downloadable in HTML link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/364946/3597276)
- [correct PHP headers for pdf file download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20080341/3597276)

Comment: Hello Michael_B, I am having problem while using japanese character on file name. My file name is mix of english and japanese character. For example $file="form申し込み用(data-form)_DOP.pdf". When I change my file name to only english then everything works well. But when I mix japanese and english character same error occurs which I have mentioned above. I thought that the problem occurred because my PDF file was corrupted. But that doesn't seems to be the real problem. I have recreated the PDF file. Can you give me any suggestion please?