# Php returned pdf fie as text/html

Tags: php, angularjs, pdf

I have a service from angular.js that call directly to node.js and everything is fine, the pdf file is application/pdf.

when I added php as middle server I run this code :

```
$output = callToExport();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: inline;filename=myfile.pdf'");
header("Content-length: ".strlen($output));
echo $output;
```

then in angularjs the result is a BLOB but the type is text/HTML

how can I fix that? 
I just need to get result from pdf service and returned it back

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correct PHP headers for pdf file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot the Encode transfer ? Like that :

```
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        $response->headers->set('Expires', '0');
```

Comment: What is `$response`? You should not introduce new variables without defining them

Comment: yeah my bad the `$response` is the equivalent to the `$output`. 
I used to code in POO.

Comment: But if you want the global header you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080341/correct-php-headers-for-pdf-file-download